# What is appropriate scope to replace this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dashboard_controller that I am using to manage users. Here is that controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if current_user.admin?
      @users = current_user.get_organization_users
    else

    flash[:notice] = "Unauthorized Page View"
    redirect_to(tasks_url)
  end
end
```

Note I am using `@users = current_user.get_organization_users`. Here is the get_organization_users method in my user model...

```
def get_organization_users
  self.organization.users
end
```

How would I replace this with a scope? I tried...

```
scope :organization_users, -> { self.organization.users }
```

...but no worky. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `scope :organization_users, -> { organization.users }`?

Comment: Why not just use `current_user.organization.users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `scope` is used to add a `class method` to your model. But you're trying to call the method on an `instance`. So, in this case, the `instance method` makes sense.

However, if you want to create a scope, pass in the `user_id` as a parameter to the scope.

```
scope :organization_users(user_id), -> { find(user_id).organization.users }
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Active record [converts scopes into class methods](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/).

That would mean that you can't replace the instance method `get_organization_users` with a scope and expect to call it on `current_user`, an instance of the class.

What you could do is create a scope and pass an argument (most probably the user id) to it, then call that scope directly on the user class.

I could give an example if you wish, but I think this approach is much longer than the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question. You want to fetch all users that belongs to the organization associated with the current user, right? In such case you should just call `current_user.organization.users`.

Scope is used for filtering records in the current model and not for getting objects that are in the relation. You can read about it in the official documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes.